# Observe value change from Cell to ViewController Swift

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

I'm in trouble because I have a TableView with inside a CollectionView and I don't know how I can pass the current data that are inside my CollectionViewCell once the user clicked on it (didSelectItemAt).

So I would wish to know if there is a way for observe the value that changed inside a variable.

For example. When user is clicking the cell, a variable is updated with the current data contained in that cell and then I'm receiving the update in my ViewController that once that has been observed the value change, will call a function for update some values in it.

Thanks!

Comment: Slightly confused by your description, as not sure which type of cell you are referring to, but to get information passed out from the embedded `UITableViewCell`  use the delegate pattern backed by an appropriate simple protocol. What you inject as the delegate target will depend on what you want to achieve.  You could use the `CollectionViewCell`, the `CollectionView`, or even go back to the `ViewController`.  For anything other than the` CollectionViewCell` you will probably need to embed some form of unique ID into your `TableViewCell` so you can work out where the delegate call came from.

Comment: Basically I have a TableView with inside a CollectionView. As I can't call "present" for open a view controller once the CollectionViewCell has been clicked, I would wish to pass some data back to View Controller using some observer. 

Is it a bit better now?

Comment: Have you looked at the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol, and the `collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)` method?

Comment: Yes sure, but the fact is that as the 'collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)' it's not called in ViewController but in TableViewCell I cannot use "present" for open a new ViewController

Comment: Still not clear if you want to respond to an action in the tableViewCell or the collectionViewCell?

Comment: @PietroMessineo If I understood correctly from your description you have a `collectionView` inside a `tableView` and you want to pass data to another `ViewController` when you click a `collectionViewCell`.Right? Also do you want to go to the `ViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the best way for hear changes is to use NotificationCenter:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("aNotificationName"), object: nil)
```

Then from my Controller:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotificationFuncName, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "aNotificationName"), object: nil)
```

Comment: This is far from being "the best way". Use callbacks or delegates for this purpose.